# SQL injections with noSQL databases?

Tags: php, mongodb, sql-injection

I am using mongoDB currently, and I am wondering what measures we should take to ensure that any data that could cause problems isn't stored. I believe that normal PHP functions like `mysql_escape_string` isn't going to help here...

Is there SQL injections for noSQL databases and especially mongoDB?
If so, what can we do to protect us from them?

Comment: I'd say you can inject as much **sql** as you want without doing harm to a **noSQL** query ;-) But it's clear what you want to know "Is there an equivalent to sql injections and how to prevent them?"

Comment: JavaScript injection is a danger but this is also described in the page that Dominic provided.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See [MongoDB's documentation](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Do+I+Have+to+Worry+About+SQL+Injection):

> Generally, with MongoDB we are not building queries from strings, so traditional SQL Injection attacks are not a problem.

There are other issues to be aware of, so it's worth giving that page a read.

Comment: reason for down voting: MongoDB's doc are pretty old indistinct and sometimes totally misleading (a.k.a wrong)

Answer (score 3):

The documentation is wrong, In PHP you need to be careful of null-byte injection attacks (http://www.idontplaydarts.com/2011/02/mongodb-null-byte-injection-attacks/) as well as object injection (http://www.idontplaydarts.com/2010/07/mongodb-is-vulnerable-to-sql-injection-in-php-at-least/)